# Yii2:Custom form Title

Tags: php, yii2

In my _form.php I am trying to change the default form title.

Actually what I want to change the text in Bold -**Create City** to **Create Custom City**

To achieve this I am trying this code, but I am getting the error like - Unable to locate message source for category 'City'.

example1

```
<?php
$this->title = Yii::t('City','Custom City');
?>
```

example 2- I am not getting any error, but the form title is also not changed.

```
<?php
$this->title = 'Custom City';
?>
```

I am putting below the whole code of `_form.php`:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;   

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\City */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$this->title = ('Custom City');

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="city-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'state_id')->DropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(State::find()->all(), 'id', 'state_name' ),
    [ 'prompt' => 'Please Select' ])?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')->textInput() ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

[image: City form view]

Comment: Dear Pawan, what do you mean by form title? in view `$this->title` is the page title. Could you please update your question with your `my_form` view?

Comment: Thanks Ali for pointing that out, I have edited my Question to reflect exactly what I want.

Comment: Hi Ali, is it clear, what I want?

Comment: Will you please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65784/yii2custom-form-title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set or change the title of _form.php from create.php.

Which means you can find in your create.php

```
$this->title = 'Create City';
```

which can be changed to anything.